# Is there a way to classify an alphanumeric string?

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification

I have data containing various items. Each item has a unique alphanumeric code associated with it (see the example below).

Is there a way to predict the item type based on the alphanumeric code?

**Data:**

```
Item          code          type
1       4S2BDANC5L3247151   book
2       1N4AL3AP1JC236284   book
3       3R4BTTGC3L3237430   book
4       KNMAT2MT1KP546287   book
5       97806773062273208   pen
6       07356196706378892   Pen
7       97807345361169253   pen
8       01008130715194136   chair
9       01076305063010CCE44 chair
etc
```

Comment: You could generate n-grams from the code (two, three or more consequent letters/numbers) as binary indicators and use lasso/elastic net to classify based on the n-grams.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. Will lasso/elastic be able to handle letters as well as numbers?

Comment: You need to dummy encode the data to get a numerical representation of the data http://uc-r.github.io/creating-text-features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a minimal implementation of (binary) text classification based on n-grams below. It's written in base R. You first need to extract the ngrams and apply some model (Lasso in my case) to predict each ngram's class. You can easily expand this to multiclass by changing the model accordingly. Note that this is just a minimal example with room to improve.

See also here: https://github.com/Bixi81/R-ml/blob/master/NLP_ngram_short_text.R

Find a Python implementation of GLMnet here: [https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet_python/](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/glmnet_python/)

**Data:**

```
# Dummy data
# Note the little differences in the strings, however there is a clear pattern
df = data.frame(text=c("ab13ab12ab16","ag16ag16fg16","ab12ab12ab12","fg12fg16fg16","ab16ab12af12","fg16fg16fg16"),target=c(1,0,1,0,1,0))

head(df)

          text target
1 ab13ab12ab16      1
2 ag16ag16fg16      0
3 ab12ab12ab12      1
4 fg12fg16fg16      0
5 ab16ab12af12      1
6 fg16fg16fg16      0
```

**Ngrams:**

```
# Set up lists to post results from loop
ngrams = list()
targets = list()
observation = list()

# Loop over rows of DF
counter = 1
for (row in 1:nrow(df)){
  # Loop over strings in first colum per row
  for (s in 1:nchar(as.character(df$text[[row]]))){
    # Get "ngram" (sequence of two letters/digits)
    substring=substring(as.character(df$text[[row]]), s, s+1)
    # Append if >1, also post row and target
    if (nchar(substring)>1){
      ngrams[[counter]]<-substring
      targets[[counter]]<-df$target[[row]]
      observation[[counter]]<-row
      counter = counter+1
    }
  }
}

# Lists to DFs
ngramdf=data.frame(ngram=matrix(unlist(ngrams), nrow=length(ngrams), byrow=T))
targets=data.frame(ngram=matrix(unlist(targets), nrow=length(targets), byrow=T))
obs=data.frame(obs=matrix(unlist(observation), nrow=length(observation), byrow=T))

# Get dummy encoding ("one hot") from all the ngrams
dummies = model.matrix(~ . -1 , data=ngramdf)

# Bind target and dummies to train DF
train = cbind(targets,dummies)
```

**Estimate some model:**

```
# Now apply Lasso to predict the classes
# https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html
library(glmnet)
cvfit = cv.glmnet(as.matrix(train[,-1]), as.matrix(train[,1]), family = "binomial", type.measure = "class")

# Predict class per ngram
classes = predict(cvfit, newx = as.matrix(train[,-1]), s = "lambda.min", type = "class")

# predicted probability per ngram -> needs (type="response")
probs = predict(cvfit, newx = as.matrix(train[,-1]), s = "lambda.min", type = "response")

# Calculate average prob that a sequence (so ngrams per row) belongs to some class
result = cbind(probs,obs)
# Get mean per row
result = aggregate(. ~ result$obs, result[1], mean)
# Bind original text and target
result = cbind(result,df)
colnames(result)<-c("observation","estimated_prob", "text", "original_target")
```

**Result:**

```
  observation estimated_prob         text original_target
1           1      0.7173567 ab13ab12ab16               1
2           2      0.3020248 ag16ag16fg16               0
3           3      0.7674571 ab12ab12ab12               1
4           4      0.2922798 fg12fg16fg16               0
5           5      0.6815783 ab16ab12af12               1
6           6      0.2393033 fg16fg16fg16               0
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, that works! I'll learn how to replicate this in Python :)